# How to hide first y-axis value?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot this chart, but I don't find the first y-axis value (*0.0*) useful. How to "skip" it?

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZnjH.jpg)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(0, 1100, 100)
y = [0.025, 0.508, 0.547, 0.566, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6, 0.605, 0.608, 0.615, 0.620]

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xticks(range(0, 1100, 100))
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Comment: By "skip", do you mean you want the axes limits to stay as they are, but not to show the tick label at 0.0, or to shift the axes up so that 0.0 is not even visible?

Comment: @gmds I'd prefer to shift the y-axis, but shorter answer will be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, this will do:

```
plt.yticks(plt.yticks()[0][2:])
```